# Dividing monopoly streets in groups

Tags: java, object-oriented

I'm new to object-oriented programming, to java, and to programming in general, and as my first real project I'm trying to program the board game Monopoly.

What I've got so far is an array that can store objects of the class *Square* (which has various subclasses, like properties, the railroads, chance cards etc.). Player objects take turns in moving around on the board, calling a *landedOn()* method for whatever square they land on. Properties can be marked with an owner, and thus this owner will receive money if someone lands on his property.

Everything is going good so far, but there is one little thing that bugs me. I'm unsure about how to elegantly divide the houses in groups, or colors. There are a couple of groups of streets on the board, and you can only buy houses if you own all properties in the group. I can imagine how to program this, but the solution seems a bit dirty and "non-general" to me. How do I make a nice general solution?

To clear up: I want to be able to check whether all properties of one type are owned by the same player, in a general way, so that if the groups are changed, a property is added, or changes group, etc., I would not have to change a lot of code.

Comment: Also the rent on unimproved properties doubles when the owner has a monopoly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant answer is probably an `Enum`.

Create an enum value for each color group, and when you create your `Property` object (which inherits from `Square`), pass the color group as a constructor parameter (since it is a *required* value to have a valid `Property`).  `Railroad`, `Utility` and the like will *not* take this parameter, since they don't have groups, and they also inherit directly from `Square` (not `Property`).*

To check whether a player has all the properties in a given group, you could use a [Lambda expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach1) if you're using Java 8, or simply have a foreach loop along the lines of

```
for (property: allProperties)
{
   if (property.getGroup() == targetGroup && property.getOwner() != targetOwner) return false;
}
return true;
```

* It would also be valid to have a `GroupedSquare` class between `Property` and `Square`, with `Railroad` and `Utility` also inheriting from it and passing a hard-coded enum value, but I think that's less elegant.

Comment: Not for calculating rent when buildings are added, but the rent increases if a player owns all 4 railroads and the rent scheme for utilities changes if you own both of them, so they do get treated in a similar fashion as color blocks.

Comment: @JeffO - I had had that thought, but since it would be the same logic to count how many `RailRoad` have a `Owner` set as it would to count how many `GroupedSquare` with a `Group` of `Railroad` have an `Owner` set, I went with the approach which divided that logic entirely.  It could go either way, though.

Comment: "..Property object .. inherits from Square". The squares on the board are not only properties - there's "chance", "GO", "Jail", for example. So then a `Square` might contain (composition/ has-a) a property, or Jail, or Chance; each with unique behavior. Just come up with an abstraction - very possibly an interface (vice abstract class) - so the `Square` handles everything the same way; calls "DoYourThing()" no matter what it is.

Comment: @radarbob - Why would you use composition here?  A `Square` **is ** a property, or a card-draw space, or Luxury Tax, or so on.  The `Square` itself is abstract.  Calling it a `Space` might be a better choice, but either works.  Separating the actual things out and having them all inherit from an interface which gets stored on the `Square` is just adding needless complexity.

Comment: I see the game board with its squares as being distinct and separate from what is done at that square. I can see how one would think of a property as a square because the game board is fixed - we can't move Reading RR. But in my mind's eye a property is not a square any more than I am a car when I drive home after work.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to an enum by Bobson might be to have the groups as independent objects. By this you don't have to iterate over all atreets to see if a group omplte but can check the individual group only. In Pseudocode the impleemntation might look like this:

```
class Group {
    Set<Road> roads;

    bool hasAll(Player player) {
        for (road: roads) {
            if (road.getOwner() != player) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
  }
}

class Road {
    Player owner;
    Group group;

    bool canBuildHouses(Player player) {
        return group.hasAll(player);
    }
}
```

Over the enum approach this has the benefit that you can mov the group specific logic all in the Group class.

Now OO designes will still not like this due to the cyclic dependency (a Group has to know its member Roads and a Road has to know its Group) which can be solved by an event-based approach this would make this specific issue notably more complex but give way more flexibility for i.e. adding special rules as one could add extra rules like bonusses if a player contains a full side of the board or all roads starting with the same letter or something quite easily.

Comment: Which one would you have inherit from the `Square`?  I assume `Road`, with `Group` being a separate class that just holds the collection of `Road`s?

Comment: Massively more complicated than a simple three line function that will be plenty fast enough.

Comment: There is something to this `Class Group` idea. The rules and rent change as all like-properties get owned by the same player. This suggests that those rules can be encapsulated by a `Group` class. This concept does not negate Bobson's answer.

Comment: a Road is the Square ...

Comment: @kevincline well, the question is which design works longtime when changing the rules a bit, or the board design or something.